# How to set GNU make to use gcc default on macos?

Tags: macos, gcc, gnu-make

```
objects = main.o kbd.o command.o display.o \
        insert.o search.o files.o utils.o

edit : $(objects)
        cc -o edit $(objects)

main.o : defs.h
kbd.o : defs.h command.h
command.o : defs.h command.h
display.o : defs.h buffer.h
insert.o : defs.h buffer.h
search.o : defs.h buffer.h
files.o : defs.h buffer.h command.h
utils.o : defs.h

.PHONY : clean
clean :
        rm edit $(objects)
```

This is an example makefile from GNU make. It says that make will use simple rules to generate *.o files with *.c files of the matching name.

However, on my mac make default use clang and I want it default to use gcc-7, in case there are some projects that give error when compiling in clang.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you would need to install `gcc`. I would do that by installing **Homebrew**, then running:

```
 brew install gcc
```

That should give you `/usr/local/bin/gcc-7` or similar. You can check with:

```
ls /usr/local/bin/gcc*
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
make CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-7
```

If you always want that compiler, edit your login profile and add a line:

```
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-7
```

and log out and back in for it to take effect.